# IMDbPY get_top250_movies() returns empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, imdb, imdbpy

When I try to get the top 250 movies from imdbpy it returns an empty list:

```
>>> from imdb import IMDb
>>> imdb_instance=IMDb()
>>> top250=imdb_instance.get_top250_movies()
>>> top250
[]
```

Any idea? The above code should return a list of the top 250 movies rated by IMDb found [here](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top). The problem is the code only returns an empty array, and not the list of 250 movies.

Comment: Motion to remove from hold. I can reproduce this on Windows with the release and SVN downloads from the supplied code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

<strike>I did: `>>>import imdb` then `>>>dir(imdb)`. [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is a very useful python function that returns the classes and functions that are under an object.</strike>

From there, I found that for some reason, the way it is written, the class `IMDbBase` contains `get_top250_movies()`, not `IMDb`. Just change `from imdb import IMDb` to `from imdb import IMDbBase` and instance that.

EDIT: Good point, @user3577702 pointed out that this is an abstract base class (oops).

The mysterious empty list seems to have been a problem for a while. I found a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/imdbpy-users/H4Sn6irSAeg) on Google Groups. According to the answer,

> The version in the SVN repository should work.

However, that is no longer the case. The current commit doesn't work.

I have started a [new question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/imdbpy-users/fjOeFDOVecM), hopefully the maintainer will respond soon.

Comment: Thanks, but the `get_250_movies()` in `IMDbBase` is abstract and not implemented.

Comment: And thanks for starting a new question!